# unix script using sed

Tags: unix, sed, string-concatenation

Im trying to get the following script to work, but Im having some issues:

```
g++ -g -c $1
DWARF=echo $1 | sed -e `s/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/`
```

and Im getting -

```
./dcompile: line 3: test3.cpp: command not found
./dcompile: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `^.+'
./dcompile: command substitution: line 3: `s/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/'
sed: option requires an argument -- 'e'
```

and then bunch of stuff on sed usage. What I want to do is pass in a cpp file and then extract the file name without the .cpp and put it into the variable DWARF. I would also like to later use the variable DWARF to do the following -

`readelf --debug-dump=info $DWARF+".o" > $DWARF+".txt"`

But Im not sure how to actually do on the fly string concats, so please help with both those issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In BASH you can crop off the extension from $1 by

```
${1%*.cpp}
```

if you need to set the DWARF var use

```
DWARF="${1%*.cpp}"
```

or just reference $1 as

```
readelf --debug-dump=info "${1%*.cpp}.o" > "${1%*.cpp}.txt"
```

which will chop off the rightmost .cpp so test.cpp.cpp will be test.cpp

Comment: Worked perfectly, and no messy sed crap. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 2):

You actually need to execute the command:

```
DWARF=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/')
```

The error message is a shell error because your original statement

```
DWARF=echo $1 | sed -e `s/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/`
```

is actually parsed like this

```
run s/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/
set DWARF=echo
run the command $1 | ...
```

So when it says `test3.cpp: command not found` I assume that you are running with argument `test3.cpp` and it's literally trying to execute that file

You also need to wrap the sed script in single quotes, not backticks

Comment: @Dgrin91 you need to use literal quotes, not backticks

Comment: Thanks, you were right. Now Im getting one more error though- `sed: -e expression #1, char 17: invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS`

Comment: Escape the slash: `s/(^.+)\.cpp$/\\1/`

Comment: Thanks, you were right again, but now my sed doesnt work. I do `DWARF=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/(^.+)\.cpp$/\1/')` and then `echo $DWARF` and get test3.cpp again (should be just test3).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` for this:

```
$ var="testing.cpp"
$ DWARF=$(awk -F. '{print $1}' <<< $var)
$ echo "$DWARF"
testing
```